# Function for assigning a value to types of digrams in a string

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to write a function that assigns a value to a string based on the *alternance* of its characters that belong to different classes.

I defined 3 type of classes:

```
digits <- "[^0-9]"
alphabetical <- "[^a-zA-Z]"
punctuation <- "[^[:punct:]]"
```

I want the function to:

- scan the string left to right
- assign the value 1 if two consecutive characters belong to different classes, 0 otherwise, performing the sum at the end.
- the more alternances the string has, the higher the value.

For example, for:

```
123d4ss
```

I want the function to assign the value '3', because the ordered characters switch first from digit to alphabetical, then from alphabetical to digit and then from digit to alphabetical again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression defines three types of groups: digits, letters, and punctuations.
If we count the number of occurrence of such groups, it will be the number you want plus one.

```
library(stringr)

regex <- "([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)|([[:punct:]]+)"

s <- "123d4ss"      # digit -> alpha -> digit -> alpha
str_count(s, regex) # gets 4

s <- ",!"           # punct only
str_count(s, regex) # gets 1


s <- ",1!Aa9"       # punct -> digit -> punct -> alpha -> digit
str_count(s, regex) # gets 5
```